# Strip off tracking from URL using R

Tags: r, string, url, substring

I have a dataframe with a column of URLs from which I want to remove everything after the first question mark. Some URLs have no question mark, and I want these to remain unchanged. In short, I want to strip off all the tracking. This is a sample URL.

> https://www.dummy.com/2017/11/29/four-questions-we-have-about-stuff/?utm_source=exacttarget&utm_medium=newsletter&utm_term=dummydotcom-dummycomnewsletter&utm_content=na-readblog-blogpost&utm_campaign=dummy

This is the result I'm looking for.

> https://www.dummy.com/2017/11/29/four-questions-we-have-about-stuff/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is called `df` and it has a column in it named `url`:

```
df$url <- sub('\\?.*', '', df$url)
```

Answer (score 2):

With `strsplit`:

```
url <- "https://www.dummy.com/2017/11/29/four-questions-we-have-about-stuff/?utm_source=exacttarget&utm_medium=newsletter&utm_term=dummydotcom-dummycomnewsletter&utm_content=na-readblog-blogpost&utm_campaign=dummy"

result <- strsplit(url, "\\?")[[1]][1]
```

Output:

```
> result
[1] "https://www.dummy.com/2017/11/29/four-questions-we-have-about-stuff/"
```

And here is an example of using it on a vector rather than a single string:

```
strings <- c("here?string", "another?string", "stringnoquestion", "one?more")

> sapply(strsplit(strings, "\\?"), function(x) x[1])
[1] "here"             "another"          "stringnoquestion" "one"
```

`strsplit` returns a list because it is written to work for vectors as well as singular elements. So in the first example the `[[1]]` was accessing the first element of the list and then the `[1]` was accessing the first element of that, the url before the `?`.

Here is the first example broken out in to steps:

```
# Returns a list of length one
> strsplit(url, "\\?")
[[1]]
[1] "https://www.dummy.com/2017/11/29/four-questions-we-have-about-stuff/"                                                                    
[2] "utm_source=exacttarget&utm_medium=newsletter&utm_term=dummydotcom-dummycomnewsletter&utm_content=na-readblog-blogpost&utm_campaign=dummy"

# Each element of the list is a vector
> strsplit(url, "\\?")[[1]]
[1] "https://www.dummy.com/2017/11/29/four-questions-we-have-about-stuff/"                                                                    
[2] "utm_source=exacttarget&utm_medium=newsletter&utm_term=dummydotcom-dummycomnewsletter&utm_content=na-readblog-blogpost&utm_campaign=dummy"

# The first element of that vector
> strsplit(url, "\\?")[[1]][1]
[1] "https://www.dummy.com/2017/11/29/four-questions-we-have-about-stuff/"
```

Comment: Thanks @efbbrown. Can you explain the function of the [[1]][1] at the end?

Comment: Sure. I've added more detail to the quesiton to explain.